# How to make np.where write True instead of 1.0?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to fill column with True and NaN values

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

my_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1' : [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]})
df['col2'] = np.where(df['col1'].isin(my_list), True, np.NaN)
print (df)
```

It prints:

```
    col1  col2
0      0   NaN
1      1   1.0
2      2   1.0
3      3   1.0
4      4   1.0
5      5   1.0
6      6   NaN
7      7   NaN
8      8   NaN
9      9   NaN
10    10   NaN
```

But it is very important for me to print bool value True, not float number 1.0. This column interacts with other columns. They are bool, so it must be bool too.
I know I can change it with replace function. But my DataFrame is very large. I cannot waste time. Is there a simple option to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Nullable Boolean data type](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/boolean.html):

```
df['col2'] = pd.Series(np.where(df['col1'].isin(my_list), True, np.NaN), dtype='boolean')
print (df)
    col1  col2
0      0  <NA>
1      1  True
2      2  True
3      3  True
4      4  True
5      5  True
6      6  <NA>
7      7  <NA>
8      8  <NA>
9      9  <NA>
10    10  <NA>
```

Comment: Forgive my incompetence! But why does NaN look like <NA> here?

Comment: @IgorK. - It is no `incompetence`. But pandas developers wanted to distingush between `NaN` and `nullable NaN`, so used `<NA>`

Comment: Perfect! You made my day and saved hours of work!!!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

This code will solve your problem. np.where will returning you true because of numpy only deals with the number and True means 1 in number. that's why it's giving you 1.0 instead of True

**Code**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

my_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1' : [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]})
df['col2'] = df['col1'].apply(lambda x: True if x in my_list else np.NaN)
print (df)
```

**Results**

```
    col1  col2
0      0   NaN
1      1  True
2      2  True
3      3  True
4      4  True
5      5  True
6      6   NaN
7      7   NaN
8      8   NaN
9      9   NaN
10    10   NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

you can call this

```
df.col2 = df.col2.apply(lambda x: True if x==1.0 else x)
```

Comment: this wont be efficient as the the other answer in manners of performance